# How to select columns from 2 tables in a Firebird database using zquery?

Tags: delphi, firebird, zeos

I would like to display on a TDbgrid data from 2 tables on a single database file. I have tried to write sql statements like:

```
select "Client", "Address", "Balance" from "table1"
and "Payment" from "table2"
```

But it always shows this error

```
SQL Error: Dynamic SQL Error DQL Error code = -104 Token Unknown - line 2,
column1 and.Error -104.Invalid token The SQL: select "Client", "Address", "Balance"
from "table1"
and "Payment" from "table2"
```

I don't know if it is not possible or I just got error on writing the code or is it the TDbgrid I need to modify. I searched for a zeos sql guide but I cannot find one. All I got was this: http://www.intitec.com/varios/A_ZEOS_basics_tutorial_not_only_for_firebird.pdf but still some of my questions are left unanswered.

I am using firebird database 2.5 and delphi 7.

What SQL code can I use on this?

Comment: "shows an error" doesn't mean anything unless you tell us **what the error is**. I'm not sure how many times you need to have this explained to you. **Be specific** when you ask questions here. (Your syntax is invalid; you should search Google for a tutorial in basic SQL.)

Comment: Edited my question. I have read some basic SQL tutorials, but the problem is that I cannot find one for ZEOS. I don't know which sql command will work on it. I just wanted to display the columns from 2 tables in a single TDdgrid.

Comment: Basic SQL is basic SQL. The fact it's Zeos doesn't matter. Google `SQL tutorial`.

Comment: I edited my question again. I want to display some columns on table 1 and 2.

Comment: Make up your mind what you want to ask, and then ask it. Changing the question again and again makes it hard to answer. It's much harder to hit a moving target, and changing the question after it's been answered makes the answers to the previous question look foolish (and wrong).

Comment: Sorry for that, I just got confused in posting my question because I am always nervous when I click the question button on this site. I also tried this: select "BALANCE" from "BALANCE" , "CLIENT_NAME" FROM "CLIENT", "PAYMENT" FROM "COLLECTION"
 and it returned the invalid token error again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29428/discussion-between-chunk-chunk-and-ken-white)

Comment: There's no need to continue this in chat. I've answered your question, and I'm not going to provide you with a private tutorial in SQL. As I said, Google "SQL tutorials". This is basic information you need to learn if you're going to work with databases (in Delphi or not).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your syntax is invalid.

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2
```

However, the above doesn't make sense either, as you're selecting every column and row from two separate tables with no means of connecting the two tables.

```
Table1
ColumnA    ColumnB
=======    =======
Nonsense   Here
Orange     Noise

Table2
ColumnC    ColumnD
=======    =======
Horse      Radish
No         Sense

SELECT * FROM Table1, Table2
```

Result:

```
ColumnA    ColumnB    ColumnC    ColumnD
=======    =======    =======    =======
Nonsense   Here       Horse      Radish
Orange     Noise      No         Sense
```

Even after your edit, there's no sense in the query.

```
SELECT Table1.ColumnA, Table1.ColumnB, Table2.ColumnC, Table2.ColumnD
FROM Table1, Table2
```

still yields the same results.

You really should look for tutorials on database programming and SQL in general. Google can help.

Comment: Got it working now. Thank you very much for your great help and guidance.

Comment: Personally, I prefer the SQL-92 `JOIN` syntax over this one (the SQL-89 variant).

Comment: @Mark: So would I, but the poster provided no information on which to base a join. It's an ongoing issue with this poster (leaving out necessary info); look at some of his other questions.

Answer (score 1):

I just got some invalid syntax on my SQL statement. And this solved my problem

```
SELECT Table1.ColumnA, Table1.ColumnB, Table2.ColumnC, Table2.ColumnD
FROM Table1, Table2
```

Thank you very much.